# Have any countries announced that they would refuse to enforce GDPR regulations?

Tags: european-union, gdpr

Given that enforcing GDPR outside of the EU would require [international cooperation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30509/how-gdpr-fines-are-actually-enforced-for-us-companies-with-no-physical-presence) it is completely possible for a country to announce they would never enforce it within their own territory.

Have any non-EU countries officially announced they would refuse to ensure compliance? The US might be a candidate but I couldn't find any official statements from them on the matter.

Comment: China's new standard is modeled after GDPR but has some differences, so I have trouble imagining China will hold its companies to the European standard, but I don't think they have exactly said that.

Comment: I've been looking for a sign from the US administration that it will or will not be enforced, but haven't found anything.  My hunch is that it will be profoundly ignored.

Comment: I think your question is based on a false premise. Many companies handling significant amounts of EU personal data have an economic presence in the EU and that can be targeted with fines. Compare the Google 'right to forget' case or Microsoft and the browser thing. In each case, the company had local offices in the EU where papers could have been served.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in more detail? How would other countries go about enforcing it?

Comment: @kweinert they could tell EU governments that any judgements against US businesses regarding GDPR will not be respected.